# How to concatenate a string with a listagg result in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use LISTAGG on Redshift to aggregate data and then concatenate a string to the LISTAGG result.

```
tmp_table:
Col1 Col2
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    A
2    B
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
SELECT 
   Col1, 
   '{"results" : "' || LISTAGG(Col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col1) || '"}' as list_result
FROM 
   tmp_table 
GROUP BY 
    1 
)
```

With the ideal result looking like this:

```
new_table:
Col1 Col2
1    {"results" : "A,B,C"}
2    {"results" : "A,B"}
```

Running this without the concatenated strings works fine, but as soon as I concatenate the string, I get:

```
ERROR:  Column length exceeds maximum allowed (maximum column length is 65535)
```

I'm sure that this does not exceed the column length, as I've checked the length of the longest LISTAGG result and it's only 30 characters. I've also trying casting the LISTAGG result as a VARCHAR(MAX), with no luck.

Comment: is this work if you only select - LISTAGG(Col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col1)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that LISTAGG automatically creates a column that is max length of 65535 so if you concatenate something to that it will give you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you convert to another string length?

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
    SELECT Col1, 
           '{"results" : "' || CAST(LISTAGG(Col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Col1) as VARCHAR(255)) || '"}' as list_result
    FROM tmp_table 
    GROUP BY 1 ;
```